# How to choose the thumbnail of the first video instead of the second video when you concatenate them with FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I've been using FFMPEG to bulk add outro to my videos. This is the code I use:

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  echo.>%%f.txt
  echo file '%%f' >> %%f.txt
  echo file 'outro/outro.mp4' >> %%f.txt
)

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   ffmpeg -f concat -i %%f -c copy concatenated/%%f.mp4
)
```

The problem is the thumbnail of the output videos is always is the second video's (the outro) but not the first. Does anybody here know how to pick the first video thumbnail to be the output's thumbnail instead of the second's?

Comment: What are you using to view the thumbnail? Windows File Explorer?

Comment: yes. I use Windows File Explorer to view the files.

Comment: Can't duplicate the issue in a Windows 7 VM using `ffmpeg` from the current git master branch. Windows File Explorer shows thumbnail from first frame of first input of a concatenated video. Show complete log of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2`. Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 professional. I don't why this happen but it shows the first frame of the second input video. What do you mean by show complete log? You mean the log generate in the cmd when I run the code?

Comment: I want to see information about your `ffmpeg` version and the details of each input contained in the `.txt` file. Run the unscripted `ffmpeg` command in `cmd`, then copy and paste the log.